# how do I escape/finish this simple bash alias on Mac?

Tags: macos, bash, alias

What I want to achieve: I input `s` in the terminal, and after 25 minutes I get a notification to take a break. Here is the code:

```
alias s='sleep 1500 && osascript -e 'display notification "break" with title "break"''
```

I get an error if I include the final `'`, and also if I don't.

Comment: You're trying to nest single quotes. It doesn't work.

Comment: oh, that's why. Is there anything I can do to achieve the same result?

Comment: Well, you could figure out how to quote it properly, but it'll probably be easiest for you to make it a function instead.

Comment: 25 minutes is a long time to `sleep`. For a more sophisticated (but not particularly _harder_) implementation, look at `at(1)` and `atrun(8)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using an alias

One can combine single-quoted strings with single quotes as follows:

```
$ echo 'a'\''b'
a'b
```

In the above, `'a'` is a single-quoted string.  It is followed by an escaped single-quote `\'` which is followed by another single-quoted string `'b'`.  In this way, one can build complex strings with single-quotes.

For your command, that would look like:

```
alias s='sleep 1500 && osascript -e '\''display notification "break" with title "break"'\'
```

#### Using a function

As @Kevin pointed out, this is simpler:

```
unalias s
s() { sleep 1500 && osascript -e 'display notification "break" with title "break"'; }
```